# Multi-value dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently in asp.net, we can have only one value in a ListItem in a DropDownList. However I hope I can:

```
<MultiValueDropDownList id="ddl" runat="server" />
ddl.Items.Add(new MultiValueListItem { Text="text", DBValue="db", EngineValue=1 });
var dbValue = ddl.SelectedItem.DBValue;
```

What I'm going to do is inherit DropDownList and ListItem. Do you guys have any better solutions?

[Closed]

At last I decide to choose a lazy way. Store the values in `ListItem.Attributes`. And using extension methods of DropDownList to help to get the collection of values. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

[EasyListBox](http://easylistbox.com/demoColumns.aspx?rl=fp)

[How to display multi-column in ASP Dropdown List?](http://forums.asp.net/p/1036228/1432282.aspx)

[asp.net : an alternative to multi-column DropDownList Gridview within dropdownlist / combobox (using the Ajax DropDownExtender)](http://oudinia.blogspot.com/2007/12/aspnet-gridview-within-dropdownlist.html)

**Edit:**

You can not inherit from `ListItem`.

See why: [Extending ASP.NET DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874873/extending-asp-net-dropdownlist)

The best solution then is to store the values inside `ListItem.Attributes`.

Comment: Well this solution can resolve this problem, but I really want other developers in this team to write "beautiful codes". Concatenating the values into one string is not so artistic, isn't it?

Comment: ah ha~ finally we have the same solution :)